# Referencing a UIButton by tag value

Tags: swift, uibutton, tags

I am aware that a pushed button can be updated by reference to sender.
However I want to access a button from the program body by reference to its tag and then update its label,if that is possible.
Suggestions on how to do this (in Swift) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

To get a button inside a view using its tag, you can use the `UIView.viewWithTag` function.

```
if let button = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton
{
     button.setTitle("newTitle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [viewWithTag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:)

ex:

```
var button = self.view.viewWithTag(tagNumber) as UIButton
button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Wow ! That's great,works just fine. I have a group of button labels to update so I have to work out how to loop through with variables for tag no and label. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Set the tag for all buttons. Then have a property

```
var buttons = [UIButton]
```

and in your awakeFromNib init it

```
buttons.append[myButtonWithTag0]
buttons.append[myButtonWithTag1]
// etc
```

Now you can access your buttons via

```
let button = buttons[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift3 : Possible with `viewWithTag(button_tag)` as:

```
let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIButton
tmpButton?.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
tmpButton?.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
```